# scraping a constantly changing integer from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-2.x

I am trying to extract numeric data from a website. I tried using a simple web scraper to retrieve the data:

```
 from mechanize import Browser
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 mech = Browser()
 url = "http://www.oanda.com/currency/live-exchange-rates/"
 page = mech.open(url)
 html = page.read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

 data1 = soup.find(id='EUR_USD-b-int')

 print data1
```

This kind of approach normally would give the line of data from the website including the contents of the element I am trying to extract. However it gives everything but the contents which is the part I need. I have tried .contents and it returns []. I've also tried .child and it returns 'none'. Does anyone know another method that could work. I have looked through the beautiful soup documentation but I can't seem to find a solution?

Comment: When I go to the website and look at the "EUR_USD-b-int" id tag it looks empty, like this: <span id="EUR_USD-b-int" class="inline_int"></span>

What do you see when you go there? I was expecting <span id="EUR_USD-b-int" class="inline_int">your int value here</span>

Comment: Perhaps that field is populated and updated using javascript. In that case, BeautifulSoup would not be able to see it.

Comment: the value I see if I inspect element in chrome is '1.37', it very likely is updated by javascript. Does anyone know a way to get the element if it is updated by javascript?

Comment: <span id="EUR_USD-b-int" class="inline_int" style="color: rgb(104, 136, 85);">1.37</span> this is what appears in the inspect element of google chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value on this page is updated using Javascript by making a request to

```
GET http://www.oanda.com/lfr/rates_lrrr?tstamp=1392757175089&lrrr_inverts=1
Referer: http://www.oanda.com/currency/live-exchange-rates/
```

(Be aware that I was blocked 4 times just looking at this, they are extremely block-happy. This is because they sell this data commercially as a subscription service.)

The request is made and the response parsed in http://www.oanda.com/jslib/wl/lrrr/liverates.js. The response is "encrypted" with RC4 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4)

The RC4 decrypt method is coming from http://www.oanda.com/wandacache/rc4-ea63ca8c97e3cbcd75f72603d4e99df48eb46f66.js. It looks like this file is refreshed often so you'll need to grab the latest link from the homepage and extract the `var key=<value>` to fully decrypt the value.

Comment: Sounds like a great solution but I think its a little beyond my capabilities. I rely on the site to trade through so can't risk being blocked by stealing data from them. Thanks though.

Comment: @user3062260 You're not "stealing" anything. It's on their website, after all. You're just using a different/custom client to access it. Any "block" is likely to be temporary.